# What are the two wires that join together near the burners in my Whirlpool oven?

Tags: oven

The model number is wfe515soewo. I'm wondering about the wire that go to the burners. It has two wires that clip into the burner and as they go towards the back of the unit they turn into one wire. What is the point of that?

Comment: Does everything work like it is supposed to?

Comment: @Kris , the wire that goes to the burner is cut. I have wire I pulled out of an old oven. the wiring on the older oven is slightly different. I would like to understand the wiring before I fix it. I know the burner is purely resistive and has no neutral and I don't know what the point is of 2 wires joining into 1  right as they reach the back of the oven.

Comment: I wonder if they're a thermal fuse.

Comment: i can't add a pic because my pics are over 2mb